# How to verify a method is called at most n times to work with InOrder of Mockito

Tags: mockito, inorder

I want to verify `getCurrentPrice()` for at most 15 times. I tried to use `atMost()` as you can see in my code, but when I ran it, it shows `AtMost` is not implemented to work with `InOrder`. How to figure out this problem?

```
@Override
public boolean validate() 
{
    String username ="Amy";
    String password = "345";
    verify(delegate,times(1)).login(username, password);
    verify(delegate,atMost(15)).getCurrentPrice(any(Cloth.class));
    InOrder protocol  = inOrder(delegate);
    protocol.verify(delegate,times(1)).login(username, password);
    protocol.verify(delegate,atMost(15)).getCurrentPrice(any(Cloth.class));     

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already verified that `getCurrentPrice` has been called at most 15 times so when testing the order of the calls you can just verify that `login` was called before any of the `getCurrentPrice` methods were called:

```
protocol.verify(delegate).getCurrentPrice(any(Cloth.class));
```

Comment: this doesnt solve it because it still says wanted 1 time but was 15 times